# PostgresSQL crypto used for column level encryption which had 10 Million rows

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, encryption, cryptography

*HI All,*

We are building a solution, after the phase 1 we were asked to secure user PI in database. By this time we have reached 10 Million user data.
We have explored few options:

1. Encryption at application side (Spring Boot side) - Having strong triple encryption technique.
2. Encryption at database side - Let DB handle encryption and decryption headache we are not bothered about it. We used JPA annotations to make our selves easy.

We went with second approach as there is wildcard search coming for encrypted data. It is not possible to get the result set if we do by application side using AES technique.

Now we could implement and everything working fine as expected. We are now facing lot of query performance issues. So we went for creating indexes. But as we already encrypted we have to create index using decrypted function otherwise index serves no purpose.

Is it safe to create index on column with decrypted information in it. The index will have decrypted data. The whole purpose of encrypted data has no significance.

```
Data Type is BYTEA and used
```

> pgp_sym_encrypt for encryption.

Similarly used

> pgp_sym_decrypt for decryption by passing key

In order to create index we have to create index as

> CREATE INDEX index_1 on table(pgp_sym_decrypt(, 'key') VARCHAR_pattern_ops);

Does the above index has any issues interms of visibility. Plus Is there any other alternatives to look for column level encryption for Postgres table and perform query optimizations by creating indexes.

Is there any other option like Securing Table space. Please throw some light on me

Answer (score 0):

Creating an index for an expression that decrypts that data will store the decrypted data on disk, yes. It sounds like you should be using encryption at the block device level (eg, full-disk encryption). Using a tablespace that points to a filesystem path where your OS is handling encryption will get you part of the way there, but even then, you should be aware that if you ever sort using any decrypted data, if the sort is ever large enough to spill out of your configured work_mem, those decrypted values will be written to temporary files. The same goes for joining using any decrypted data, as the query planner will often use a sort as part of the query plan when a join is present.

If your requirement is that decrypted data never be written to disk, you should really be using OS-level features; that's not something the database server can do on it's own without severe restrictions (like never using expression indexes that decrypt values and never sorting or joining on decrypted data).

Comment: Thanks Adam for your response. Even I had the same opinion about encryption at column level.